# Sitecore sites element clarification

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

newbie to sitecore. Could someone please help me understand how the  element below works, please? And, what sort of scenarios do I need to update  it.

```
<sites>
      <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" disableBrowserCaching="true"/>
      <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true"/>
      <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
      <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service"/>
      <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
      <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>
      <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false"/>
      <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore"/>
      <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore"/>
      <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
    </sites>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a configuration for the sites for `Sitecore` application. Every request is matched for all of the sites in this configuration and **first** matched `<site>` node is used to determine `database`, `rootPath`, `startItem` and other properties.

In a single site scenario for **Sitecore** application, most probably you won't need to change it - just use the standard config and place your content under the `sitecore/content/home` node.

You will need to change it if you're planning multi-site application though - add another `site` node with proper `hostName`, `virtualFolder` and other properties.

More information can be found [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx). And [here is an example](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/Examples.aspx) of how to add a new site to your `Sitecore` application.

Comment: Thank you, what if I deleted the out of box Home Content Item and created Content > MySite > Home > Page A . And, when user visit my website I would like them to show Home item above. Do i need to modify the existing <site name="website".... elment?

Comment: Yes, you should update the **rootPath** to `rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite"` of the **website** site.